# How to combine two matrices.?

Tags: matrix, physics, education

let **A**, **B**  are any 4 by 2  Matrices , i want to know whether it is possible to obtain a 4 by 4 matrix by using equation **A=B**

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, but Join[A,B,2] should work

Comment: dear i am studying a paper in which a 4 by 4 matrix is formed by using A=B

Comment: Can you post a link to the paper you mention?

Comment: Perhaps the point is that A=B can be solved by row reducing [A|B] (if there is a unique solution)

Comment: Use John's suggestion, which is better than mine, which would be `ArrayFlatten[{{A,B}}]`